# How do I add a span under an input without having anything move?

Tags: css, input, html

Here's my sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/AemFJ/

```
<div class="new_field">
<label class="field_names" for="whatver">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="whatverfield" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<div class="empty_spacer"></div>

<div class="new_field">
<label class="field_names" for="whatver">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="whatverfield" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<div class="empty_spacer"></div>

<div class="new_field">
<label class="field_names" for="whatver">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="whatverfield" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<div class="empty_spacer"></div>

.empty_spacer {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

[image]

The empty space is great but when there is an error i want to use that space to show a message like "First name is missing."  I am trying to do it by putting a span in .empty_spacer under the field but when I use it is significantly below the input.

What I want to do is using the space to show a span that uses the same space but doesn't add  any more space.

Comment: You should check out Tipsy for error messages. It does all of the work for you, and doesn't take up more space. http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Answer (score 0):

You could try perhaps wrapping these labels and inputs into a 3x2 table.  This would control the spacing not changing and only display the relevant "spacer" row when needed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `line-height` instead of `margin-top`
but for that you have to put any character for space like `&nbsp;`

here is the fiddle :

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin4dotnet/AemFJ/1/)